# How do I embed a YouTube video in a card comment in Trello?

Tags: youtube, trello

This is not a common problem.
Because when I paste a YouTube URL into a comment on card in Trello, sometimes it just ends with an embedded YouTube video which is just what I want, however, sometimes it won't work. The comment will show a plain hyperlink as I pasted in which is not good.
How to solve this problem?

Comment: Do you have an example of a youtube link that *isn't* working?

Comment: oh，yeah, of course, you can check this board,https://trello.com/board/board-1/4e70d794c726d2f1c200b1a1 there is a comment in one card of the To Do list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Trello uses [embed.ly](http://embed.ly) to generate previews for certain types of links, including links to youtube.

If you go to [embed.ly](http://embed.ly), you can test it with that URL (http://www.youtube.com/twitterapi#p/u/7/HY5GIl7sFwE), and see that it isn't able to get a proper preview (because the link isn't in a format that it recognizes)

However, if you use a link like http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HY5GIl7sFwE (which points to the same video), that *is* in a format that embed.ly recognizes, so Trello is able to get the preview.